# return success data while subscribing in extend .ts file from component in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to return success(result) data from .subscribe in component when extending as .ts file

Is it a good idea to extend a ts file like `appConfig` and consume method/result in respective components from where method called using return value.

Does it have affect on  components that is extending same single `appConfig` file?

## app.component.ts

```
export class viewComponent extends appConfig OnInit {
constructor(
public service: httpservice
){
super(service);
}
getData(){
        let data = this.mserviceCall('resolveId',"sjsjs-1092");
        debugger;
        if(data && Object.keys(data).length > 0){
            alert(data) <=== data is required here
        }
    }
}
```

## app.component.html

```
<button class="btn" type="button" (click)="getData()">Get</button>
```

## appConfig.ts

```
public mserviceCall(type, id) {
    const _self = this;
    if (type === 'resolveId') {
        let _params;
        _params = {
            'kid': id
        };
           this.serviceInvoker.invoke('resolve.information', _params).subscribe(
            (result) => {
                if (result) {
                    return result;
                }
            },
            (error) => {
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: In general you can't return anything from a `subscribe` callback. You should subscribe in your component where you actually want to work with the returned data.

Comment: The issue is same method mserviceCall is used by serveral components and just writing same piece of code is little cumbersome hence, trying to utilize same piece of code.

Comment: To alter your response, perform side effect or handle errors you should use [rxjs operators](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/) that you `pipe` to your observable in your service. You can do all the shared logic with `operators` in your service. All you have to do in your components is subscribe and display the data. This might even allow you to use the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) in your components so you wouldn't have to subscribe manually at all.

Comment: Is this not a good idea to subscribe and utilize 'success (result)' from service in appConfig.ts which is extended class instead of a component itself.

Comment: No. You should follow the general angular guidelines as described in the tutorial and documentation. See [Angular Services Observable Data](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#observable-data)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good idea to extend a ts file like appConfig and consume
>   method/result in respective components from where method called using
>   return value.

I don't think so. You should consider using a service instead, to separate different roles in your application (logic and view).

> Does it have affect on components that is extending same single
>   appConfig file?

No, they are different instances.

Comment: I recommend the first part of the [Angular - Services tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4), it explains exactly what you need now.